# The need for bind or apply for partial application

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on the partial application section of the [functional javascript workshop](https://github.com/timoxley/functional-javascript-workshop).

Specifically I need to:

> Use partial application to create a function that fixes the first argument to console.log.

With the example output:

```
var info = logger('INFO:');
info('this is an info message');
// INFO: this is an info message
```

My naive solution works but doesn't use apply or bind:

```
function logger(namespace) {
  return (args) => console.log(namespace, args);
};

const info = logger('INFO:');
info('this is an info message');
// INFO: this is an info message
```

The recommended solution:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice

function logger(namespace) {
  return function() {
    console.log.apply(console, [namespace].concat(slice.call(arguments)))
  }
}
```

What am I missing?  Why are bind or apply necessary?

Comment: Try `info('this is an info message', 123)`, and you will see that your solution passes only the first argument. The recommended one, however, concats all of them with namespace and passes the result into `console.log` via apply.

Comment: Whats the point of `console` as the first argument to apply?

Comment: It's the context object (`this` inside the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended solution will pass through all arguments (and maybe was written without respect to ES2015). Your solution will only pass through the first arg. I think you're looking for `(...args) => console.log(namespace, ...args)`.